# Integral of infinitely high curve

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the integral of the curve $\frac{1}{x^3}$ bounded by $y = 0, x = 3$. I am unsure of how to take the integral when I have no real lower limit. Is there a way for me to set the lower limit to the limit of $f(x)$ as it approaches 0?

Comment: Try setting the lower bound of the integral as k, and taking the limit as k approaches 0 of the integral. It turns out this limit does not converge, so the integral doesn't either.

Comment: There are two possible regions here - either $x<3$ or $x>3$. Which one is intended? You haven't provided enough information to determine.

Comment: @jmerry he wants $x < 3$ from what I can infer, because otherwise the title wouldn't be named "Integral of *infinitely high* curve" ;)

Comment: @KKZiomek but he does not say bounded by $x=0$ despite saying bounded by $y=0$

Comment: @Henry I'm reasonably sure it's a typo, and he means $x = 0$ instead of $y = 0$.

Comment: Your question isn't clear as those two lines don't bound the given function. Do you mean for $\;x>0\;$ ? Do you mean $$\int_3^\infty\frac{dx}{x^3}\;?$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that (by definition)
$$
\int_{0}^3\frac{1}{x^3}\, dx=\lim_{a\downarrow 0}\int_{a}^3\frac{1}{x^3}=\lim_{a\downarrow 0}\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}\right]_{a}^3
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: If that is the integral the OP meant then it doesn't converge

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the tiny sliver below the black curve and above and to the right of the red lines in this picture

[image]

then you want $$\int_{x=3}^\infty \left(\frac1{x^3}-0\right) \, dx  = \left[-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right]^\infty_{3} =\frac{1}{18}$$